# UI / UX Review Site?

Tags: gui-design, ux-field, expert-review

I stumbled upon a UI/UX review site some time ago, but cannot seem to put my finger on it again.  Could someone please advise if you are aware of what this site may be?  I have a few designs I'd like to pass in front of a pro level crowd for review and suggestions.

Comment: You mean : http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/47773/design-review?referrer=o6wFHCmdV_IzGVpiaspDYA2

Comment: Here's a new site (year 2017) that focuses on usability testing & feedback: https://usability.testing.exchange/ (I'm developing it).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[22 web design critique websites to help get feedback](http://www.underworldmagazines.com/22-web-design-critique-websites-to-help-get-feedback/). Most of these are focused on graphic design, but I think that a few do UX as well.

Comment: Of these, http://conceptfeedback.com, http://feedbackarmy.com, http://fivesecondtest.com look promising (in terms of focusing on UX).

Comment: ConceptFeedback is great! Usually very thorough and lots of great feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Since you specifically mentioned "pro level crowd," [Concept Feedback](http://www.conceptfeedback.com/), the first site listed in Vitaly's link, might be the one you want.

I'm not familiar with the site, but it looks like the idea is you can solicit feedback from on or more [experts](http://www.conceptfeedback.com/users/experts/) at the cost of $99 per expert.

Of course, if you have [questions about specific aspects](/faq) of your designs, and others might benefit from the answers, you can ask us for free. :)

Comment: +1 But - A Lot of the feedback on Concept Feedback is free.

Comment: You can earn your own reviews by reviewing others as well.

Comment: @Matt Since you're familiar with the site, feel free to post a better answer. I'll delete this one. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [ratemyux.com](http://ratemyux.com/). They provide several UX analysis packages with different costs and features. I used the cheaper one but Steve (the owner, I think) upgraded the package for free since it's a new service they are offering.